# Force reload of JAVA WAR from inside JAVA

Tags: java, war

Is there a way from inside a JAVA WAR to programatically ask the App Server to relaod the WAR.  I need to reboot my web application daily and was hoping that I can force the reload from inside the application itself.  Aka System.forceReload() or something similar .... any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Could you "touch" a file such as web.xml to trick the container into initiating a reload? Very hacky, I know :-)

For a more robust solution, I'd be thinking about an external cron script, I must admit, possibly to brute force stop/start the container itself. This would probably be "better" in terms of remediating any memory leaks, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately the WAR is in the cloud and I have no easy programatical access to the container - just a web console that I log into to control the application ...

Comment: Ah, trickier then; could you control via a URL directly, e.g. http://www.hostname.com/manager/reload?name=myapp ? Guessing no, but worth asking...

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to do such thing from inside the application.

Better approach would be to do it externally. You can schedule scripts which can do the same thing for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the WAR is hosted in the cloud so ive got no filesystem / OS to use ...

Answer (score 0):

It may vary depending on your container, but I've not seen this sort of functionality in the containers I've used.

Although I can understand your need, I'd suggest a better way would be to bounce the container itself if you can, perhaps using a cron job.

If you're using JBoss you might be able to do something with the [Twiddle Utility](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch2.chapter.html)

JMX / MBeans could also be an option - but again, all of these are outside of the actual application.

Comment: I've just seen your comment below (re in the cloud) - in GAE (google) you can schedule tasks in a cron like way, possibly including the app itself.  Is this an option for you?

Comment: Will ask the container provider if this is possible.  There just doesnt seem to be any task manager etc in their web front end.  Thx